# Showing only last six months in a dropdown

Tags: date-time

I have a month column (a choice column) in my document library. Its format is, for example, "Jan 2013".

I have the following requirements:

1. The month dropdown should always show only the previous 6 months relative to the current month.

   For example, if the current month is March 2013, then only the months starting from October 2012 to March 2013 should be populated in the dropdown
2. There is another column in my document library called "date", which is in a date format. It should not be shown in the default view. The date field should automatically be set as the 1st date of the month selected from the month column.

   For example: If the month selected is March 2013, the date should be `1/3/2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late response.. You're right, there is no "NewForm.aspx" on document libraries.
So what can you do is adding the following javascript to the "EditForm.aspx" file of the related document library. You've to edit "EditForm.aspx" file in advanced mode by using SharePoint Designer. Add these code after PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea tag.

In your document library one single line of text field (called as **Month** in my code) and a Datetime field (called as **Day** in my code).

This javascript first hides the textfield for Month field and shows a dropdown list that includes last three months.

Probably you've to optimize the javascript code :) But I tried it in my environment, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("addItemsToCombo");

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

function addItemsToCombo()
{
    var today = new Date();

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i=0; i<inputs .length; i++)
    {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute("Title")=="Month")
        {
            inputs[i].setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            var select = document.createElement("select");
            select.setAttribute("name","tempMonth");
            select.setAttribute("id","tempMonth");
            var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
            var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = "Select";
            option.setAttribute("value", "");
            select.appendChild(option);
            for(j=0; j<6; j++)
            {

                var option = document.createElement("option");
                if (currentMonth<0)
                {
                    option.innerHTML = month[currentMonth+12] + " " + (currentYear -1);
                    option.setAttribute("value", currentMonth +12 + " " + (currentYear -1));

                }
                else    
                {
                    option.innerHTML = month[currentMonth] + " " + currentYear;
                    option.setAttribute("value", currentMonth + " " + currentYear);
                }
                select.appendChild(option);
                currentMonth = currentMonth-1;
            }
            select.onchange = function() {monthChange();};
            inputs[i].parentElement.appendChild(select);
        }

    }

}

function monthChange()
{
    var combo = document.getElementById("tempMonth");
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i=0; i<inputs .length; i++)
    {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute("Title")=="Month")
        {
            inputs[i].value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
        }
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute("Title")=="Day")
        {
            var selectedMonthYear = combo.value.split(" ");
            var mm = parseInt(selectedMonthYear[0]) + 1;
            var yyyy = selectedMonthYear[1];
            if (mm<10)
            {
                mm = "0"+mm;
            }
            var firstOfMonth = "01/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;
            inputs[i].value = firstOfMonth;
            inputs[i].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank u So much Kerem...For ur help and support...But I am Facing a couple of issues..
1.When I am Placing the code inside PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea the month column is populating fine..but in th month column i also need the current month to be populated.
2. When i am selecting an element from the month column.. message box pops out saying "objectHTMLSelectElement"..
3.The Date field is showing the 1stday of current month...But I want It to be 1st day of selected month.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Thank u So much Kerem...For ur help and support...But I am Facing a couple of issues..
1.When I am Placing the code inside PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea the month column is populating fine..but in the month column i also need the current month to be populated.
2. When i am selecting an element from the month column.. message box pops out saying "objectHTMLSelectElement"..
3.The Date field is showing the 1stday of current month...But I want It to be 1st day of selected month.
Thanks in Advance...:) :) :) :)

Comment: Please Give Me the Solution Soon..Its Really Urgent...Thankss..:)

Comment: Code is updated. Now it should fit you needs :)

Comment: Thanks A lot kerem...You Are an angel....You Made My Day..Thanks A ton.....:):):)

Comment: I'm glad to help you :) Maybe you can mark this as answered if it is ok for you :)

Comment: Can i ask u a Final question?? i hope i am not troubling u...now i am not able to sort on the basis of the date column..I want to sort the documents i uploaded either in ascending or descending value of the date..out of the box sorting is not working on date column..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible by default SharePoint columns. 
Here are the possible solutions:

- In the Page_Load event of the NewForm.aspx you can write a code that
  changes or inserts the items in the combobox.
- You can write a javascript in NewForm.aspx that uses DOM to insert new items to the combobox.

You can use a javascript code like this: http://keremozen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/addItemToCombo.js

Hope these help

Comment: Kerem ..Thanks A lot For your solution..But Can u Please Elaborate On the second solution you gave ...about Javascript??

Comment: I am totally new To Javascript..So have absolutely no idea about it

Comment: I added a sample js file to my answer. It should work with one or two modifications. You have to use this code in NewForm.aspx file of your document library.

Comment: But I am Working On a Document Library ..Not A List ...So NewForm.aspx is not available by default..plus my requirement also states that the 'date' column field should automatically be populated with the 1st day of the month selected from the month column..I am Very Confused...Please Help

Comment: Problem is solved..:) just changed the date format...thanks a lot..:)